# Excel VBA Create and Add multiple rows in Table from two dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a UserForm1 in Excel that when a user adds in a start date and end date - it will then create new rows in a table1 that populate as follows using VBA:

```
Example: User enters - START DATE: 5/9/2020 & END DATE: 5/16/2020
```

Table Returns (Rows and calculations added to table1):

```
DATE          COUNT          P1/P2       START DATE      END DATE
5/9/2020        1              1          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/10/2020       2              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/11/2020       3              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/12/2020       4              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/13/2020       5              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/14/2020       6              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
5/15/2020       7              2          5/9/2020       5/16/2020
```

**Date Column Shows:** start date and a row for every day between 5/9 and 5/16 but not including 5/16

**Count Column:** Counts the rows added off one input

**P1/P2 Column:** Shows 1 for the first row added (record only) off the command and 2 for all the rest

**Start Date:** Shows the date entered as [start date]

**End Date:** Shows the date entered for [end date]

If someone enters a date that has 365 days in it, the table would end up with 365 added rows. Hoping to find a simple way I could do this like I would with SQL - but I haven't been able to find any examples in VBA.

I've been able to input data from a button on the userform which adds to the table at the end - I'm really needing direction on how to create multiple rows and manipulating the data to do what I want it to in VBA.

Appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write your entire program for you but this example solution will give you a working model to work from. I'll post some code and then explain what it's doing below.

***Note:*** I am creating a new workbook, with default worksheet names and a new UserForm with all default names for the form and it's controls.

UserForm Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim DateRangeLength As Long
Dim LoopCounter As Long
Dim RowAfterLast As Long

StartDate = CDate(Me.TextBox1.Value)
EndDate = CDate(Me.TextBox2.Value)

DateRangeLength = (EndDate - StartDate)

With Sheet1
    For LoopCounter = 1 To DateRangeLength
        RowAfterLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If LoopCounter = 1 Then
            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = StartDate
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = 1
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = StartDate
            .Range("E" & RowAfterLast).Value = EndDate
        Else
            .Range("A" & RowAfterLast).Value = StartDate + (LoopCounter - 1)
            .Range("B" & RowAfterLast).Value = LoopCounter
            .Range("C" & RowAfterLast).Value = 2
            .Range("D" & RowAfterLast).Value = StartDate
            .Range("E" & RowAfterLast).Value = EndDate
        End If
    Next LoopCounter
End With

End Sub
```

I pass both the dates from the userform to `StartDate` and `EndDate` respectively using the `CDate()` function which converts it to a date value (otherwise you *might* experience problems with some dates).

I find the difference between the dates as an integer and assign it to `DateRangeLength` which is declared with the `Long` data type.

Then using a `For...Next` loop with DateRangeLength as the upper bound of the loop, we write the data to the worksheet. In my example the range is between columns `"A"` and `"E"`. The row is found at the start of each loop iteration by finding the last used row in column A and adding 1 which is assigned to `RowAfterLast`.

### Screenshots:

The output range and UserForm ready to click 'Go!' with test data: 
[image: Empty output range]  [image: UserForm with test data]

Output after the code is run:
[image: Output range after test data is run]

---

### I should mention

You would be wise to add some kind of error checking with your user input data, such as some statements or function that makes sure the value is a valid date and in the right format.

Google is your friend if you're not too sure what to do or where to start with this.

To give you a good example of why this is important, if I enter the date values in your question *in their format* of **MM/DD/YYYY** I end up with no output because of my date settings - the correct format for my reigon is **DD/MM/YYYY** so the start date `05/09/2020` is understood as `September 5th, 2020` and the end date is understood as `05/16/2020` but because there is no 16th month, translates to your intended `May 16th, 2020` which results in `DateRangeLength` equalling -112 and as such the loop exits without even starting the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks Samuel! This should point me in the right direction. And looks great. I have experience with creating error checking and probably mandatory in the situation - so I should be able to take care of those.